# Mod_Rewrite Issue. CSS & Images no longer load

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am working on a website. I have the mod_rewrite rules set up and they work great. But the css and images no longer link correctly. I have tried various methods found around the web and none seemed to work. So all help is appreciated.

```
File Structure 

assets -> css, images, js, header.php, footer.php, global.php
controllers -> login.php, register.php, etc.
functions -> Various functions
view -> login.php, register.php, etc.
.htaccess
index.php
```

I am attempting to create a cleaner mvc structured web app. ( cleaner than my previous app )

```
.htaccess

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 


RewriteRule ^login$ controllers/login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ controllers/logout.php [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^register$ controllers/register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register/(.+)$ controllers/register.php?ref=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^news$ controllers/news.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ controllers/news_inner.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ladder/(.+)$ controllers/ladder.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&    page=standings [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ladder/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/ladder.php?platform=$1&game=$2&    url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournaments$ controllers/tournaments.php?platform=$1&game=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournament/(.+)$ controllers/tournament_inner.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=info [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournament/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/tournament_inner.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/team/(.+)$ controllers/team.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/team/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/team.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ controllers/profile.php?url=$1&page=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/profile.php?url=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/game.php?platform=$1&game=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I am using this same mod_rewrite that i am using on a separate website that is currently live and is full functional ( no css/image issues ) so i am not really sure what is wrong. I have tried the  solution, the request_filename solution, all have not worked so i am assuming it is something wrong with my rewrite.

Oh i forgot to mention in the header file all of the css files have an absolute path

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$url/assets/css/reset.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$url/assets/css/style.css' />
```

I am also now experiencing issues with the last rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/game.php?platform=$1&game=$2 [QSA,L]
```

i sort of understand why, but again the changes i make do not seem to work. Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i saw was this part of code

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

This is **not** for all rules but only the first after conditions.
I made your htaccess cleaner, try this

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If this is an existing file or folder, do nothing and leave
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If we reach here, this means it's not a file or folder (avoid rewriting on your files like css, etc)

RewriteRule ^(login|logout|register|news)$ controllers/$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register/(.+)$ controllers/register.php?ref=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ controllers/news_inner.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/profile.php?url=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ controllers/profile.php?url=$1&page=main [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ladder/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/ladder.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ladder/(.+)$ controllers/ladder.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=standings [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournament/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/tournament_inner.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournament/(.+)$ controllers/tournament_inner.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=info [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/tournaments$ controllers/tournaments.php?platform=$1&game=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/team/(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/team.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/team/(.+)$ controllers/team.php?platform=$1&game=$2&url=$3&page=main [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ controllers/game.php?platform=$1&game=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I swapped some rules because you're using `(.+)` pattern which match everything (too large) and leads to priority problems.

I also noticed you're using everytime `QSA` flag and i suspect you don't really know what it does. I didn't remove those flags from your code but you can find more information about it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) and see if you need it

Comment: thank you for that, it worked. The only issue i am left with is the last rewrite rule. It interferes with all other rules, and it causes the css to be seen as MIME type containing html not css. Do you have any solutions in mind for the last rewriterule?

Comment: I don't understand why your last rule would interfer with other rules, since i did put in the end of your htaccess (other rules are evaluated before) and no rule are evaluated if this is an existing file or folder. Do you have an example (or more) of url you tried when your problem happened ?